# Are there any limitations how much storage can RasPi handle?

Tags: pi-3, hard-drive, storage

I was thinking about creating a storage farm.

I have absolutely no idea if there are any limitations of storing multiple TBs of data.

Are there any physical limitations regarding **amount and speed** of the storage?

Comment: One disadvantage is that Ethernet and USB are shared lowering the throughput.

Answer (score 1):

The size limitation for drives is a SATA-Issue...the Raspberry has no SATA routines in it's BIOS.

Usually you have only USB-Ports to connect peripherals, so there are no limits by the USB-controller interface on the size of data-storage.
BUT..., these slow USB-2 Ports have shared access with the Ethernet-Adapter. This means you will be slow as hell with many disks connected to them.

You may use an additional controller board for your project solution.
Look for **"raspberry pidrive"** and get an **X8XX Controller board** to attach.